# How this representation is called?

Tags: logical-operators, mathematical-expressions

If I tell you that the following

```
X ⊕ X
```

represents an `xor` operation between 2 arguments `X`, How you name this kind of logical/math representations for logic operations ?

The table that recaps the properties for all the common logic operations used in the programming world has a special name ? With *property* I mean something like `X ⊕ X = 0` .

Answer (score 1):

This is the Boolean algebra. See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra to begin.

The particular expression you ask about is called "idempotency" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).

What exactly do you mean by a "table that recaps the properties for all the common logic operations" ?

Boole algebra has a few basic rules, like De Morgan, then several different types of relations/properties as the one you quote, but to my knowledge there is no general table regrouping all of this (except perhaps a wiki page if that's what you mean ?).

Comment: `idempotency` is the math term, `X ⊕ X = 0` is more useful in real world programming, it's easier to read and think about. I guess that what I'm looking for could be called "table of binary arithmetic properties".

Comment: Ok... I'm not sure such a table exists. As you can see on the wiki pages, there are many similar porperties, most of which can (more or less ?) easily be rededuced from the basic ones, which are De Morgan and the properties that make the Boolean algebra... an algebra :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would just call the ⊕ a "logical symbol" or "Boolean operator", similar to ¬ (NOT), ∧ (AND) and ∨ (OR).

For all of these logical operators more than one symbols exist; the ones shown here are maybe most used in the context of Boolean algebra.

A table depicting the result of logical operations together with its input parameters is called truth table.

Resources:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(logic)#Basic_operations

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table

Comment: so if I'll ask to random people to write down some boolean expressions the will adopt this representation ? There is really no name for this ?

Comment: if they have some basic skills in Boolean arithmetic or logical equations, I'd say yes ... and not that I know of ... all literature I have makes use of one set of symbols, most of them telling tht "in other literature you find symbols xyz" ... ask the same questions for symbols like +, -, &times;, &divide; ... what would the answer be?